# Changing calling javascript function variable with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There is a html page like this:

```
<div id="list"><a onclick = "javascript:addplaylist('shv231a','1');" href="javascript:void(0);">+</a></div>
<div id="list"><a onclick = "javascript:addplaylist('jhr2a13','1');" href="javascript:void(0);">+</a></div>
<div id="list"><a onclick = "javascript:addplaylist('thy2b1k','1');" href="javascript:void(0);">+</a></div>
```

There are javascript functions

```
 addplaylist('shv231a','1');
    addplaylist('jhr2a13','1');
    addplaylist('thy2b1k','1');
```

I want to change value '1' with '2' in javascript function (addplaylist) when user click this

```
<a id="make2" onclick="" href="javascript:void(0);">Change the value 2</a>
```

How can I do that with jquery?

Answer (score 2):

The way to do this with jQuery is to move all of the Javascript code into a separate file or `script` block within the HTML.  Any way which abstracts the display (HTML + CSS) from the behavior (Javascript)

This will require a bit of reworking of the HTML.  In particular removing the duplicate id fields in favor of having id's be unique.  Additionally removing the javascript references from the `onclick` handler.

```
<div id="list1"><a>+</a></div>
<div id="list2"><a>+</a></div>
<div id="list3"><a>+</a></div>
```

Then with jQuery you can specify the behavior of these links directly from the JavaScript.  This is true for both the play list links and the one which modifies them to pass '2',

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

  var secondArg = '1';

  $('#list1 a').click(function (e) { 
    addplaylist('shv231a1', secondArg);
    e.preventDefault();  // Don't follow link
  });

  $('#list2 a').click(function (e) { 
    addplaylist('jhr2a13', secondArg);
    e.preventDefault();  // Don't follow link
  });

  $('#list3 a').click(function (e) { 
    addplaylist('thy2b1k', secondArg);
    e.preventDefault();  // Don't follow link
  });

  $('#make2').click(function (e) {
    secondArg = '2';
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible solution:

```
<a id="make2" onclick="javascript:changeToTwo();" href="javascript:void(0);">Change the value 2</a>
```

Javascript

```
function changeToTwo() {
    $('div#list a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('onclick', $(this).attr('onclick').replace("'1'","'2'"));
    });
}
```

If I remember right ie will only select 1 element with the same id so you may want to consider moving it to a class selector

Answer (score 0):

1) Ids should be unique on a page
2) use a class to select
3) keep your functional code out of the markup

HTML:

```
<div id="1" class="list"><a>+</a></div>
<div id="2" class="list"><a>+</a></div>
<div id="3" class="list"><a>+</a></div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.list').each(function ( index, element) {
    addplaylist(element.id);
});
```